# Access not permitted. You are not authorized to perform this operation (AMQ4036)

Tags: ibm-mq

I have installed MQ server on HP Nonstop and client version 8 on windows server. When i am trying to access MQ server via websphere MQ explorer on windows i am getting Access not permitted,You are not authorized to perform this operation (AMQ4036) error. Can you guys help me here?

Answer (score 3):

If you look in the AMQERR01.LOG on the queue manager it will tell you the reason you were rejected access. There are several different possibilities for security failures, but the exact nature of your failure will **always** be found in the error log. If you are not sure of the meaning of what you find in the error log, update your question with more information and I will update this answer with more information too.